# cannot click dropdown items on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar like the one below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#works">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

with CSS:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
 background: #eeeeee;
 position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 top: 40px;
}
}
```

The navbar works properly on larger screens. The mobile screen is the problem. It works properly when used in desktops (i.e I have a mouse to click the links). However, when used using mobile devices (i used an iPhone), the links of the navbar are not working anymore. What's more, I cannot toggle the dropdown button anymore once I've clicked on something.

If it helps, here's the codepen link: [codepen](http://codepen.io/kingjami/pen/rrLRKK?editors=1100)

**EDIT:** I found out now that the navbar is not working when I am using Safari on my iPhone. When viewed in Google Chrome it works just fine even if in mobile. Any ideas as to why it is not working in Safari? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That codepen works on mobile...

Comment: wow really? I can't click them on my iPhone though. I'll try different mobile devices to check. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I will go ahead and try it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code with a wrapper div.

```css
.nav-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
 </div>
   
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I did it already and it worked smoothly. However, I am still having problems when I use Safari (i.e I cannot click the navbar list items). It's working fine when used in other browsers, however.

Comment: @gsuxlzt I have updated the placement of nav-wrapper div. Please try that.